# Could you share a link to a good catalogue of Linux distros to choose?

Tags: distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you choose a distribution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-do-you-choose-a-distribution)

I'd like to see a list of all the Linux distros by their mission (like generic, firewall, mail server, free-only, enterprise, virtual machines host, virtual machine guest, audio production, etc.) with basic description and analytics (like first release date, package management system, development activity, people behind the distro (like core team size or, for example "Canonical corporation" for Ubuntu) release cycle description, popularity, etc.). Where can I find such a catalogue?

I've tried distrowatch.com, but couldn't find any classification there. I'd like to be able, for example, to see "all the distros meant specially for a firewall (or a LAMP server) deployment", or "all the distros available as LiveCDs" etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions - anything more detailed you'll likely have to find out for yourself as trying to keep track of 'em all is a Sisyphean task.

Comment: I don't think you'll find something more accurate and comprehensive than distrowatch

Comment: question is very similar to [1426](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-do-you-choose-a-distribution), might get some answers there

Comment: I'm on the fence about calling this a duplicate, but the answers there probably cover this question too

Comment: I would also like to find a table, listing most distros, if a live CD is avaible, what packaging system is used, what size roughly the distro is, etc. Just a clean table. And is such a table dosn't exist (as is shown by the above comments), this is not a fault of the question! If I had the reputation, I would vote to reopen!

Comment: Aaaaand 5 minutes later, the answer to my question: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions)